# Calculations for time elapsed in days

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with multiple sheets each sheet has the same layout with Date in column "A" and Time Elapsed in column "P" I need to calculate days between column A and today on all four sheets. If checkbox in column "N" is set to true then instead calculate column "O" from "A".
So far I have been able to code this bit but, need help getting over the hurdle.

```
function getDateDifference(event) {
  var ss = event.source;
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Alpha'); // I need this to run on all four pages
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var startDate = sheet.getRange(3,1).getValue(); 
  var endDate = new Date();
  var duration = (endDate - startDate)
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (r.getColumn() == 14 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var endDate = sheet.getRange(3, 15);
    var duration = (endDate - startDate); 
    sheet.getRange(3, 16).setValue(duration); 
}
else {sheet.getRange(3, 16).setValue(duration);}
}
```

Example sheet for reference
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OKFoS17le-Y5SAOecoLE4EJxiKqKVjRLRHtMzwHNwxM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). You may also try the [Blank sheet maker here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383).

Comment: Exact copy of [Calculations for time elapsed in days](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/169087564).

Comment: This would be easy to do with the `datedif()` spreadsheet function or simple subtraction. Why is it necessary to use a triggered script function? Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Comment: I have tried something similar to your reply. I could not get it to work properly. I need the checkbox to populate current date in adjacent cell. In my spreadsheet I have changed the headers to "Date" column "A" "Coached" column "N" column P should be today minus column "A" This is calculating the time from a form submission to current date. If checkbox is checked/Yes stop calculating "P-A" and now calculate "O-A" Hope this helps clarify. If not I'll be hanging out in my example sheet.

Comment: You are attempting to insert timestamps with iterative calculation and the formula `=IF(N4="Yes",IF(O4,O4,TODAY()),"")`. That will work for a time but at some point those formulas are bound to get recalculated, and you will lose all the timestamps. Use a script to insert a permanent timestamp, and turn off iterative calculation. It causes all kinds of unexpected trouble.

Comment: @JonBeckner you have apparently unshared the sample spreadsheet. The best practice is to leave your demo sheet shared for reference. You can reshare it as view-only if you wish.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676). It is unclear if by "today" the OP means the current day, dynamically, or if they want a static timestamp together with a formula to show the duration between the timestamp and another date. The OP has not shown sample data in the question and has unshared their sample spreadsheet. I think the question should be closed unless the asker edits the question to clarify their desired result.

Comment: The OP has not addressed the issues raised regarding the question. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

#### Calculate Diff in Days for selected sheets

```
function calcdiffindays() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const incl = ['Alpha', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'];//Add the desired sheet names
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate());
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => ~incl.indexOf(sh.getName())).forEach(s => {
    s.getRange(3, 1, s.getLastRow() - 2, s.getLastColumn()).getValues().forEach((r, i) => {
      if (r[13] == true) {
        let d = new Date(r[0]);
        let dv = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
        s.getRange(i + 3, 15).setValue(DiffInDays(dtv, dv));
      }
    })
  })
}

function DiffInDays(Day1,Day2) {
  if(Day1 && Day2 && (Object.prototype.toString.call(Day1) === '[object Date]') && (Object.prototype.toString.call(Day2) === '[object Date]')) {
    var day=86400000;
    var t1=new Date(Day1).valueOf();
    var t2=new Date(Day2).valueOf();
    var d=Math.abs(t2-t1);
    var days=Math.floor(d/day); 
    //Logger.log(days);
    return days;
  } else {
    throw 'Invalid Inputs';
  }
}
```

Test Sheet:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 | COL11 | COL12 | COL13 | COL14 | COL15 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/1/2022 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | TRUE | 3 |
| 7/2/2022 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | TRUE | 4 |
| 7/3/2022 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | TRUE | 5 |
| 7/4/2022 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | TRUE | 6 |
| 7/5/2022 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | TRUE | 7 |
| 7/6/2022 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | TRUE | 8 |
| 7/7/2022 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | TRUE | 9 |
| 7/8/2022 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | TRUE | 10 |
| 7/9/2022 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | TRUE | 11 |
| 7/10/2022 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | TRUE | 12 |
| 7/11/2022 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | TRUE | 13 |
| 7/12/2022 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | TRUE | 14 |
| 7/13/2022 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | TRUE | 15 |
| 7/14/2022 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | TRUE | 16 |
| 7/15/2022 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | FALSE |  |
| 7/16/2022 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | TRUE | 18 |
| 7/17/2022 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | FALSE |  |
| 7/18/2022 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | TRUE | 20 |
| 7/19/2022 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | FALSE |  |
| 7/20/2022 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 | TRUE | 22 |

> You appeared to be attempting to use a trigger.  However, you did not specify a trigger and there were no triggers defined in your spreadsheet.  So I went without triggers.

#### An onEdit Version:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const incl = ['Alpha', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'];//Add the desired sheet names
  const idx = incl.indexOf(sh.getName())
  if (~idx && e.range.columnStart == 14 && e.range.rowStart > 2 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    const dt = new Date();
    const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate());
    let d = new Date(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).getValue());
    let dv = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(DiffInDays(dtv, dv));
  }
}
```

Comment: Not really what I was after. I replied to another person with clarification.

Comment: So I gather you wish to utilize an onEdit trigger; is that correct? That triggers on column 14 checkbox TRUE

Comment: Yes that was my goal

Answer (score 0):

To insert timestamps in column `O` when the checkboxes in column `N` are ticked, use a timestamping script such as [yetAnotherTimestamp_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/135269995?msgid=135276870) with these parameters:

```
    // [START modifiable parameters]
    {
      sheetName: /^(Alpha|Beta|Charlie|Delta)$/i,
      watchColumn: ['N'],
      stampColumn: ['O'],
      watchRowStart: 3,
      watchRowEnd: +Infinity,
      timestampFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
      overwriteTimestamp: true,
      eraseTimestampOnDelete: true,
    },
    // [END modifiable parameters]
```

Then put this formula in cell `P2`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    "Days Elapsed"; 
    if( N3:N = "Yes", O3:O - A3:A, iferror(1/0) ) 
  } 
)
```

The formula will give the number of days between the timestamp and the form submission in the rows where a checkbox is ticked.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. I don't understand how my issue became so complicated. All I am after is a simple if statement. subtract "today's date" from column "A" if column "N" is "Yes" then subtract column "O" from "A". if I've missed the answer please don't hesitate to educate me. I tried an array formula and that didn't work. I wrote some script but its incomplete. Again please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: The array formula I gave you gets the difference between `O` and `A` when `N` is `Yes`. The script I linked puts the timestamp in `O`when `N` is clicked.

Comment: But does it calculate "Today()" - "A" until checkbox is yes?

Comment: No. The formula gets the difference between `O` and `A` when `N` is Yes. When you click a checkbox, that is the same number as the number of days from `A` to today. But the next day it will still be the same number and will not increase as days go by, unless you click the checkbox again. Why are you asking these questions? Test the code to verify that the results are what you wanted.